# Why is my layout breaking when I use LocationButton?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location

The LocationButton from CoreLocationUI seems to break on scrolling.

Here's an example:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocationUI

struct LocationButtonBrokenView: View {
    @State private var txt: String = "Test"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Group {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                VStack {
                    Text("Where are you?")
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Text", text: $txt)
                        LocationButton() {
                            print("Get location")
                        }
                    }
                }
                ForEach(0 ..< 8, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
            Group {
                ForEach(0 ..< 9, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LocationButtonBrokenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocationButtonBrokenView()
    }
}
```

Everything renders as expected when the view first loads:

[image: Fine when the view loads]

But then it's trash after you scroll down and back up:

[image: Trash after scrolling]

Comment: I'm only using Group as a convenience to add enough items to force the view to scroll. Group isn't relevant to the issue here, and the issue appears in my actual code where there is no group present.

Comment: Try removing id:\self and making custom sub Views instead of Group. But it looks to me like the Vstack has lost its height.

Answer (score 0):

After seeking help on Reddit, I have come to the conclusion that the button itself is buggy. Apparently something about the UITableCellView is breaking the height calculation for the button. The workaround involved setting a minimum height on the greatest ancestor of the button within the List view. Here is more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/ud650r/locationbutton_breaking_layout/